# How to post data from Iphone to sqlserver

Tags: iphone, wcf

I want to ***post*** data from Iphone to Sqlserver using WCF REST service....
In Iphone i have a dictionary(with 5 K-V pairs) &  want to pass a single element of this dictionary
(like Id )through webservice(Browser) ......& save all the other K-V pairs in Sqlserver corresponding to this Id using the method made in Wcf service.
Plz Any help....................

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to call wcf service from Iphone](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3227385/how-to-call-wcf-service-from-iphone)

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/982622/consume-wcf-web-service-in-objective-c-on-an-iphone , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/891090/iphone-net-wcf-interoperability , and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2244764/iphone-web-service-calls-to-wcf-service-with-certificate-authentication

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [ASIHTTPRequest](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/), which is a framework that makes it easy to [issue POST requests](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/How-to-use#sending_a_form_post_with_ASIFormDataRequest) to RESTful services.

**EDIT**

It looks like you have a JSON object. You can parse JSON into an `NSDictionary` using [`json-framework`](http://code.google.com/p/json-framework/). There are numerous tutorials you can access through Google that explain how to parse JSON with `json-framework`.

Once you have your `NSDictionary` of key-value pairs, it is trivial to use ASIHTTPRequest to create a POST HTTP request. The [code samples](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/How-to-use#sending_a_form_post_with_ASIFormDataRequest) on ASIHTTPRequest's site explain how to create a POST request.

I'm not sure what WCF is, but so long as it understands POST requests, you should be able to use ASIHTTPRequest for talking with it.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Can you edit your question to indicate what the exact problem is?

Comment: Hi Alex...
I have a Dictionary in Iphone with 5 K-V pairs & i want to post these 
K-V pairs through Post method & save the values of these K-V pairs in sqlserver using WCF service.
Till now i have post data from Iphone but...i cant't handle it in WCF service.
bcoz the WCF service i will make will take only a single argument(Id
-one of K-V pair) & want to save the other K-V pairs corresponding to this key.....
have i explained u..??

Comment: I want something like that
http://209.62.6.226/GracoRest/service.svc/Rest/Profile/107
The 107 is one element of K-V pairs of Dictionary & it returns all the other K-V pairs in this Dictionary